# Read file character by character using MIPS in MARS IDE

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

How can I loop until the end of file without hardcoding the the value of $t0

```
        addi $t0, $t0,1000

loop:   beq $t0, $0, loopend
        #this code reads in a character from the file
        jal readchar


#print the character to the console
        li $v0,11
        move $a0,$t1
        syscall

        addi $t0,$t0,-1
        j loop
loopend:

readchar:   li $v0,14
            move $a0,$s6
            la $a1,inchar
            li $a2,1
            syscall
            lb $t1,inchar
            jr $ra
```

Because when I use $a2 it doesn't work, but it says here http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html

that 
read from file

li $v0,14
$a0 = file descriptor

$a1 = address of input buffer

**$a2 = maximum number of characters to read    $v0 contains number of characters**

And when I use this as substitute for the hard coded ($ addi $t0, $t0,1000)
$a2 is still 0

```
li $v0,14
move $t0,$a2
sycall
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what purpose moving `$a2` to `$t0` *before* the system call would serve. `$a2` is an argument to the system call where you specify the maximum number of characters to read. The return value - i.e. the number of characters actually read - is available only *after* the system call, and will be in register `$v0`.

So if you put 1 in `$a2` before the system call and `$v0` contains zero after the system call, then you've probably reached the end of the file.